# xcodebuild -exportArchive fails with error Locating signing assets failed

Tags: ios, ipa, xcodebuild, xcode9-beta, xcode9

I'm using command line xcodebuild tool to export .ipa files from Xcode archives. It was working fine up to Xcode 8.3.3. The same setup has stopped working with Xcode 9 beta. Now it fails with this error:

```
IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fc309310550>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed."
```

It seems Xcode 9 cannot locate the provisioning profiles, but why?

Comment: What are the concrete xcodebuild commands you're executing?

Comment: Please try it! > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271606/xcodebuild-commands-failed-to-generate-ipa/55042136#55042136

Answer (score 13):

In my case the issue was solved by the next fields in the `-exportOptionsPlist` plist:

```
<dict>
  <key>compileBitcode</key>
  <false/>

  <key>method</key>
  <string>ad-hoc</string>

  <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
  <dict>
      <key>com.my.bundle.id</key>
      <string>AD_HOC_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME</string>
  </dict>

  <key>signingCertificate</key>
  <string>CERTIFICATE_HASH</string>

  <key>signingStyle</key>
  <string>manual</string>

  <key>teamID</key>
  <string>TEAM_ID</string> 
</dict>
```

So, apparently I had to set: `compileBitcode`, `method`, `provisioningProfiles`, `signingCertificate`, `signingStyle` and `teamID`.

In your case the set of fields can be different. I have found out my set by archiving and exporting the `.ipa` through Xcode 9. Xcode will export its `exportOptionsPlist` with the ipa and show what fields it used.

More info on the fields discovery: https://blog.bitrise.io/new-export-options-plist-in-xcode-9

Comment: Thank you! worked for me. compileBitCode is not part of the signing-issue and may not be needed. Should be marked as solution...

Answer (score 11):

I was running this command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath archive.xcarchive -exportPath /my/export/path -exportOptionsPlist options.plist
```

My project uses manual signing. It turns out Xcode 9 needs the provisioning profile names or UUIDs specified in options.plist in order to sign the exported .ipa file. I added this entry to my options.plist:

```
<key>provisioningProfiles</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.myapp.bundle.id</key>
    <string>My AdHoc Provisioning Profile Name</string>
</dict>
```

And the error "Locating signing assets failed" was gone. However there was another error:

> IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "ipatool failed with an exception: #

Xcode 9 recompiles the app from bitcode by default. I got over this error by turning bitcode off by adding another entry to my options.plist:

```
<key>compileBitcode</key>
<false/>
```

Now I'm finally able to build my app with Xcode 9 and export ipa files with xcodebuild without errors.

Comment: We've tried this (both with the UUID and what we think the name is) and we're getting the same error. xcodebuild telling you *where* it is looking, *which* profiles it is trying and why they are not suitable would be very helpful.

Comment: Anyone figure out what the actual cause of "NonZeroExcitException" is? Turning off Bitcode isn't an option for us

Comment: Some useful information related to NonZeroExcitException: It is coming from the python script bitcode-build-tool during the archive step. Xcode creates logs in a temporary folder. For me it's: /var/folders/62/wwfl967573n9f1g2yqg_3zg80000j_/T/MyApp_2017-09-18_10-32-23.314.xcdistributionlogs These logs contain more detailed output from the script. It looks like there's some issue with bitcode in the export step.

Comment: Thought I'd follow up for anyone stumbling across this on Google. If you have nested projects in Xcode, make sure all libraries linked into your subproject are also linked into the top-level project under both Link Libraries and Embed Binaries, especially when Bitcode is enabled. The bitcode tool pulls its command line arguments from the top-level link list, and if you're missing any, it'll barf with the terribly named but fortunately easily Google-able "NonZeroExcitException"

Comment: It works for me on XCode9. for the "My AdHoc Provisioning Profile Name", I replaced it with the UUID from downloaded file *.mobileprovision, line after "<key>UUID</key>".