# xcodebuild commands failed to generate iPA

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcodebuild

In xcode 9.2 I'm generating archive using automatic signing, Developer certificate and provisioning profile are generating through xcodebuild commands using `-allowProvisioningUpdates` key.

But when generating iPA through xcodebuild commands with that archive getting below error.

```
Details:  Unable to close provisioning ledger entry because not all of its subentries are closed
Object:   <IDEProvisioningLedgerEntry: 0x7f925ced3840>
Method:   -closeWithError:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f925a734df0>{number = 4, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Using Xcodebuild command to generate archive

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath '/path/to/archive/Test.xcarchive' -exportOptionsPlist '/path/to/exportOptions/ExportOptions.plist' -exportPath '/path/to/archive/' PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="bundle_id" DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="development_team_id" -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

And Export plist options details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>iPhone Developer</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>automatic</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    <key>uploadBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Using Xcode GUI all working fine, Developer, Distribution certificate and provisioning profile are generating

But when using xcodebuild in terminal only developer certificate is generating and developer provisioning profile when archiving. but Distribution certificate is not generating through xcodbuild.

Can any one help me!

Comment: Have you tried fastlane? Helps a lot

Comment: @iWheelBuy Do you have any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I recommend to use https://github.com/openbakery/gradle-xcodePlugin
I use it on my project for 2 years and it works event I update Xcode

Comment: @iWheelBuy I'm using fastlane and it produces the same error.

Comment: Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? For me the distribution certificate was not created, so used `-allowProvisioningUpdates` option and then got this error.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it's useful.

> xcodebuild archive -workspace "xxx.xcworkspace" -scheme "xxx" -configuration Debug -archivePath build/xxx.xcarchive
>
> xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/xxx.xcarchive -exportPath build/xxx -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my organization we have different `team_id` for Development and Distribution

If it's the same for you then perhaps specifying the Distribution Team ID in the xcodebuild command would fix the problem.